# R save within a function, preserve the original inputs name

Tags: r

I want to save within a function, using the input object's name as the file name

```
saveNew <- function(dat){
    # Collect the original name
    originalName <- deparse(substitute(dat))

    #Do lots of Fun and Interesting Things!

    #Now lets save it, First i have to get it
    newToSave <- get(originalName, envir = .GlobalEnv)

    save(newToSave, file = paste0(originalName, '.Rdata') )
}
```

But the problem is when i go to save it, it saves the newly created data as `newToSave`. This is apparent when loading this newly created object with

`load('funData.Rdata')` the object is no longer `funData` but now `newToSave`

How can i get this function to save it as, in the example below, `funData`, as well as load it as `fundata`, not `newToSave`.

Example:

```
funData <- sample(seq(1,1000,.01))

saveNew(funData)

load("funData.Rdata")
```

Comment: You might have missed `{` after `function(dat)`. Otherwise, it saves `funData` on my machine.

Comment: @RonakShah, Its when i load this object it that the object is named originalName. I'll update the question to mirror this

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang Thanks for the suggestion. I reframed my question a bit better.

Comment: Still the same. It saves `funData`.

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang, Ive significantly altered the question to better represent the problem. This main issue is when you load fundata.Rdata, the object that you load is not the correct name

Comment: I got it. I have added a line to your code `load("funData.Rdata")` to show the problem.

Comment: I'd better use `saveRDS` for this. Check `?saveRDS`

Comment: @PavoDive I've been struggling with understanding pros and cons for saveRDS. Could you point me in the direction?

Comment: @MadmanLee please see my "answer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `assign` to assign `dat` to `originalName`

```
saveNew <- function(dat){
    # Collect the original name
    originalName <- deparse(substitute(dat))

    #Do lots of Fun and Interesting Things!

    assign(originalName, dat)

    save(list = originalName, file = paste0(originalName, '.Rdata') )
}

# Sample data
funData <- 1:10

# Save
saveNew(funData)

# Remove funData from the current environment
remove(funData)

# Load the RData object
load("funData.RData")

# Confirm that funData is in our current environment
funData
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Note that we need to use `save` with the `list` argument to enforce that `save` writes the value that has been assigned to `originalName`.

Comment: Bravo! I have tried various ways to assign `originalName` within `save` without success.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This isn't really an answer, but as the OP wanted more clarification on the pros and cons of `saveRDS`, I thought I could put those under an answer. **If you consider it should be deleted, please state so in a comment (before downvoting) and I'll be happy to withdraw it**.

From `?saveRDS`:

> Details:
>
> These functions provide the means to save a single R object to a connection (typically a file) and to restore the object, quite possibly under a different name.  This differs from ‘save’ and ‘load’, which save and restore one or more named objects into an environment.  They are widely used by R itself, for example to store metadata for a package and to store the ‘help.search’ databases: the ‘".rds"’ file extension is most often used.

`saveRDS` is specifically aimed at saving **one object**, while `save` can save one or more, but for me the main difference is that `save` and `load` bring back the object to life with the same name it had when saved, so one of its potential drawbacks is that it could rewrite an object already in the environment, whilst `saveRDS` and its companion `readRDS` can save and load objects *to different objects*.

From `?load`:

> Warning:
>
> ...
>   ‘load()’ replaces all existing objects with the same names in the current environment (typically your workspace, ‘.GlobalEnv’) and hence potentially overwrites important data.  It is considerably safer to use ‘envir = ’ to load into a different environment, or to ‘attach(file)’ which ‘load()’s into a new entry in the ‘search’ path.

Consider this:

```
save(iris, "save_file.rdat")
iris[1, 2] <- 20000 # implement a change to iris
load("save_file.rdat") # overwrites iris

saveRDS(iris, "my_file.RDS")
iris[1, 2] <- 20000 # introduce a change to iris
new_iris <- readRDS("my_file.RDS") # modified-iris is kept. New object is created
```

Comment: I think this is great as I haven't seen tla description as clear as this

Comment: So, with savRDS, if i am saving a list a list of 5 dataframes and i only made changes to 2 of those 5 dataframes. This funciton will only save those 2 dataframes which keeping the others unchanged, thus speeding up my save?

Comment: With `saveRDS` you only save **one object at a time**. That means you only save the variable you need to save